# Google Sheets query that searches multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I currently have a search function I got from a tutorial and I'm wondering how I can modify it so that when I type key words into B1 it will search for the key words in columns A thru G on the workshop tab instead of just column D. I left the code I currently have below:

```
=QUERY(Workshop!$A$1:$G,"SELECT * WHERE LOWER(D) LIKE LOWER(""%" &JOIN("%"") AND LOWER(D) LIKE LOWER(""%", SPLIT($B$1," "))&"%"")",1)
```

Here is a link to the sample spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nCNMpe2peJUWerUP8fgjMHxTiIwgUyZoM5GAW1PnoQo/edit?usp=sharing

I tried replacing the "D" with "A:G" and I also tried replacing it with "A,B,C,D,E,F,G" and neither worked. I don't know what else to try, I am still so new to this! I couldn't find anything on Google about it either!

Comment: can you share a sample-demo sheet?

Comment: I just did, thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

instead of searching through all columns you can collapse them into one and search it there and then not include it into the output:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(QUERY({Workshop!A:G, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Workshop!A:G),,99^99))}, 
 "where lower(Col8) contains '"&LOWER(B1)&"'", 1)), 99^99, COLUMNS(A:G))
```

[image: 0]

ofc there are like 20+ levels of how strict or smart you want that search to be...

Comment: awesome as always, what does the `99^99` argument do ?

Comment: Wow that's awesome thanks! Come to think of it there actually were layers of complexity I wanted to add I just wasn't sure the proper way to ask how I guess? 

Like I wanna be able to have like buttons in the sheet I can press to indicate which columns I wanna search through, as well as which columns I want displayed in the search results. It would also be nice to be able to rank the rows in order of date or "rank" if that is even possible, but if not oh well XD